# Openlayers 3 documentation

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

Where can I find information about OpenLayers that is actually useful? I'm trying to convert an OpenLayers 1 application to OL3 and the documentation seems to be non-existent or a very simple example that doesn't come close to helping me figure out my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I too, just started learning OpenLayers recently and spent quite a bit of time looking for additional resources and examples especially because experimenting with examples is how I learn best.

This is a [great resource](https://leanpub.com/thebookofopenlayers3/read#sc2-getting-ready), called "The book of OpenLayers 3". Not sure why, but you can view the entire book for free from that link (confirmed as of June 15, 16).

I also found [this link](http://openlayersbook.github.io/index.html) very useful. It has many examples from the OpenLayers Beginners book (below).

And the last thing I can suggest is to get yourself a copy of "OpenLayers 3: Beginner’s Guide" (purchased or otherwise). This will probably give you the best understanding of OpenLayers...plus it will goes side-by-side with the examples in the 2nd link.

BONUS: (harrywood.co.uk/maps/examples/) has some more examples. Couldn't post a direct link because I can only post 2 links with my newbie account.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the OpenLayers 3 website at http://openlayers.org/?

There you will find [examples](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/), the [API documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/), a [quick start tutorial](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/quickstart.html), [more tutorials](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/) and a [workshop](http://openlayers.org/workshop/).

Comment: I have seen this, thanks...the examples are much more basic than what I need to do and that is why I'm looking for additional documentation.